# C# API - Get Different Data Types as Input to Post Function

Tags: c#, sql, api, post, get

Currently I have a POST function which returns me the hash after logging in with the correct credentials. I want to, after getting that hash returned, copy it to the body - something like

> "auth_hash": *hash_value*

And get the content from my database back. Do I have to use a GET for this (if so, how do I send the hash as the input for validation) or is there any way for the POST to receive diffent data types (being the first a json object with the credentials and the second a string)?